# Adding a primary key to a lookup table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5, primary-key

We are using GUIDs for all of our SQL tables at work, and I was asked to create a lookup table to between 2 existing tables because of a many to many relationship between the tables.  Let's say the original tables are Account, and AccountOwner. Accounts can have multiple owners, and AccountOwners can own multiple accounts.

So I create the lookup table as:

**AccountOwnerAccount**:

```
AccountId , GUID, (not null)
AccountOwnerId, GUID, (not null)
```

Several days later I was asked to add a primary key field to this table. This seems completely redundant since the combination of `AccountId` and `AccountOwnerId` will always be unique.

The new table would look like this:

**AccountOwnerAccount**:

```
Id, GUID, (not null) 
AccountId , GUID, (not null) 
AccountOwnerId, GUID, (not null)
```

The only logical reason I can see is that this will allow this table to show up in our Entity Framework `.EDMX` by doing this. Without it, the EDMX already knows exactly how to work with the lookup table, but doesn't allow you to get `AccountOwnerAccount` entities. To me that is the way it should be.

I would like to know if others think it is a good or bad idea to add a new Primary key field as I'm being asked to do, or should I request that we stop that practice? I'm not asking this for people to be on my side, I just want to know the best practice here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Although the table is comprised of GUIDs, which, as you say, would be unique in combination, they reference equivalents of themselves in other tables. They function as foreign keys and are therefore dependent on information in the other two tables. It is safer to have a completely separate and unique primary key. When combining data sets (lets say from another location) things can become complicated if you don't have a single GUID column and indeed SQL Server will put one on in the process of setting up what is called Publishing and Distribution. For this reason you might as well stick it on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure SQL terms that concatenated key is perfect.

But there are other non-SQL considerations for a PK as you mentioned. I have run into issues with various software you can use to build your automated scripts for database deployment. The main issue I run into is if no PK is defined at all (visual studio database project schema compare tool will just ignore any tables without a PK and not even tell you about it), but I have seen concatenated keys cause scripting problems or get skipped entirely. This is a moot point if you write your database rollout scripts manually or know your publishing tool well enough to correct the unwanted behavior.